# How to autoplay the list of image in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

We are developing a shopping cart application using Xamarin in visual studio 2019, My question is ,I want to autoplay slide left to right from the list of image, Give me the solution to resolve this issue

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Shopping.Pages
{
    public partial class GalleryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public GalleryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> students = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Manikandan.png",
                    "RajKumar.png",
                    "Suresh.png",
                    "Karthick.png",
                    "Prakash.png",
                    "Kavin.png",
                    "Aathif.png",
                    "Prabhu.png",
                    "Aravind.png",
                };

            listViewCarousal.ItemsSource = students;
        }

        void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped1(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`GalleryPage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Shopping.Pages.GalleryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <controls:CarouselViewControl Grid.Row="0"
                                          Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                          InterPageSpacing="10" 
                                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                          x:Name="listViewCarousal" 
                                          ShowIndicators="True">
                <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl>
            <Image Source="Autoplay.png"  Grid.Row="1">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Note: When I click the *autoplay* image then I'd like to present the list of images as a slide show.

Comment: Is this the `CarouselView` from https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView? You seem to be missing the namespace import in your XAML ...

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to CarouseViewControl automatic slider, @Paul's point works fine, but you can also do this simply.

```
private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped1(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (Func<bool>)(() =>

        {

            int currentIndex = listViewCarousal.Position;
            int nextIndex = currentIndex < listViewCarousal.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count() - 1
                                 ? currentIndex + 1
                                 : 0;
            listViewCarousal.Position = nextIndex;

            return true;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it is my solution, you save my time

Comment: @P.Thiyagu, If my reply solved your issue, please remember to mark as answer, thanks

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. I have used similar method in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about [this view](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarouselView.FormsPlugin/), you can simply set or bind the `Position` property of the `CarouselViewControl`. As long as `CarouselViewControl.AnimateTransition` is `true` (which should be the default as far as I know), the `CarouselViewControl` will animate the transition between the items when you set the `Position`.

You could implement the following method in your code behind:

```
private void SelectNextImage()
{
    int nextImageIndex = GetNextImageIndex();
    listViewCarousal.Position = nextImageIndex;
}

private int GetNextImageIndex()
{
    int currentIndex = listViewCarousal.Position;
    int nextIndex = currentIndex < listViewCarousal.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count() - 1 
                         ? currentIndex + 1 
                         : 0;
}
```

Which can be called from a timer method

```
using System.Threading;

// in constructor
this.slideshowTimer = new Timer(SlideshowTimerElapsed, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinity);

private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped1(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // this starts the timer, you'll hopefully be able to figure out 
    // how to stop it by yourself
    slideshowTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

private void SlideshowTimerElapsed(object unusedState)
{
    // since we are on another thread
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(SelectNextImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here my code 

void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _isRunning = true;
            RunTimer();
        }

        void Handle_Tapped_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            _isRunning = false;
        }

        //this is for timer

        private bool _isRunning;

        public void RunTimer()
        {

            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), () =>
            {

                int currentIndex = listViewCarousal.Position;
                int nextIndex = currentIndex < listViewCarousal.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count() - 1
                                     ? currentIndex + 1
                                     : 0;
                listViewCarousal.Position = nextIndex;

                return _isRunning;
            });
        }
```

Comment: It seems that you have solved your problem, so you can mark your reply or my reply as answer, it depends on you, thanks.

Comment: I need to be able to implement the pinch to zoom gesture on the images, any ideas?

Comment: ,If you want to zoom for Image, you can take a look:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/zoom-in/, but I think it doesn't work for CarouselViewControl, because CarouselViewControl is the Container, there are many image in it, so it doesn't work for it.